# the terminal emulator configuration in the UFT

Tags: terminal, automation, qtp, hp-uft, terminal-emulator

I have a problem because I have been sharing try to get a solution.
I'm trying to configure the Terminal Emulator on HP-UFT, but unfortunately do not know even begin.
I would want to install something before the UFT configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create a new GUI test. If you don't, the Terminal Emulator option will not be displayed.

1. Launch UFT 11.5x or 12.00
2. Select Terminal Emulator from the addins window
3. Once UFT is loaded, select File>>New>>Test
4. Select GUI Test
5. Click Create button. Wait for new test to appear.
6. Click Tools>>Options>>GUI Test
7. On the left hand side, you should see Termial Emulator under Windows Applications
8. Click Terminal Emulator and configure as needed.

You will get more details if you'll simply search `terminal emulator configuration in the UFT` on google.

Comment: Thank it has been of great help.

but unfortunately, since this research. and always shows the request-HLLAPI DLL installation

Comment: Check this link. http://addin-uft.blogspot.com/2013/12/configure-terminal-emulator-in-uft-qtp.html